# diagonal lines from the top right trying to draw on a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've got a tablet called a Slate that I can process x,y points from. I can pass these x,y points to my "drawShape" function, the equivalent of a touchesMoved function. I have a custom UIView class designed for this purpose with 4 main functions. The first three are touchesbegan/moved/ended and there is a drawRect.

Here's the source to the UIView subclass...

```
//
//  DrawingLayerView.m
//
//
//  Created by Monica Kachlon on 12/3/17.
//

#import "DrawingLayerView.h"
#include "UIBezierPath+Interpolation.h"


@interface StrokeA : NSObject

@property (assign, nonatomic) CGPoint startPoint;

- (id)initWithStartPoint:(CGPoint)point;


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * points;

@end

@implementation StrokeA



- (id)initWithStartPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    self = [super init];
    self.startPoint = point;
    self.points = [NSMutableArray array];

    return self;
}


@end



@implementation DrawingLayerView

NSMutableArray * strokes;
NSMutableArray * points;


StrokeA * currentStroke;
UIBezierPath * currentPath;
UIBezierPath *path;
UIBezierPath *pathTwo;

UIBezierPath *Newpath;
CAShapeLayer * currentLayer;


- (void) noodlez
{
path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

   currentPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    pathTwo = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    Newpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
     strokes = [NSMutableArray array];
     points = [NSMutableArray array];

}
- (void)startTouch: (CGPoint)point
{

    currentStroke = [[StrokeA alloc] initWithStartPoint:point];
    [strokes addObject:currentStroke];
}

- (UIBezierPath *)createPath {
    UIBezierPath * bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    for (StrokeA * stroke in strokes) {
        [bezierPath moveToPoint:stroke.startPoint];
        for (NSValue * value in stroke.points) {
            [bezierPath addLineToPoint:[value CGPointValue]];
        }
    }
    return bezierPath;
}


- (void)endTouch: (CGPoint)point
{

    [points removeAllObjects];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
- (void)drawShape: (CGPoint)point
{
    if (!currentStroke) {
        [self startTouch:point];
    }
    [currentStroke.points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
    pathTwo = [self createPath];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [pathTwo stroke];
}


@end
```

And here's the screenshot.

[image]

I tried writing "Ok?" Just to illustrate the issue.

Comment: You need to include enough code so someone else can see what you are doing, in order to help figure out what you're doing wrong. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Not sure as to what other information you need. These are the 4 main functions that the program operates around.

Comment: Some helpful folks around here may want to run your code to help you debug it... what you've posted cannot be run. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that the code is lacking some detail and the question is poorly worded, the screenshot is clearly showing that the initial point for the path is (0,0) in each case. Dump the points in the paths out to the console and you'll see it. Figure out how those (0,0)'s are getting in there and you'll solve the problem.